# plot 3d surface of pre-defined function

Tags: r, 3d

I want to plot 3D surface of pre-defined function which include switch statement.If I run my code, *"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" and "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found"*  these two are printed without result I intended. Simplified code is as below. Anyone can fix this problem?

```
    BlackScholes<-function(S, K, r, q, vol, T, result){

    switch(result,
     callprice = S+k+T,
     putprice = K+T,
     calldelta = exp(-q * T),
     putdelta = exp(-q * T)
     }

     x<-seq(1950000,2700000,by = 5000)
     y<-seq(0,30,by = 1)
     f<-BlackScholes(x,220000,0.014,0,0.2,y,"calldelta")
     z<-outer(x,y,f)
     persp(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save your function call in `f`, you are saving *the result of the function*, not the function call itself. In order to use your function as the `FUN` parameter in `outer()`, you should pass the named parameters of `BlackScholes()` as extra arguments to `outer()`.

```
z <- outer(
  x, 
  y,
  FUN = 'BlackScholes',
  K = 220000,
  r = 0.014,
  q = 0,
  vol = 0.2,
  result = 'callprice'
)

persp(x,y,z)
```

Also, you should probably refrain from naming any variables `T`, since it's R shorthand for the logical `TRUE`.